# Spring MVC Form Validation Custom Error with Parameters/Tokens/Arguments

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

My Spring MVC form validation is working, but how do I expand parameters or "tokens" in my .properties file?

E.g.:
**messages.properties**

```
error.field.required=<b><a>{0}</a></b> is required
```

Spring MVC Validator class which adds the error/code:

```
@Component
public class MyModelValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return MyModel.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

        MyModel myModel = (MyModel)target;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "address.addressLine1", "error.field.required");

    }

}
```

I need to pass in a custom string, such as "**Address Line 1**" to replace the {0} token with a description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass values for message placeholders using `errorArgs` parameter of the [`rejectIfEmpty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/ValidationUtils.html#rejectIfEmpty-org.springframework.validation.Errors-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-) method.

```
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors,
        "address.addressLine1",
        "error.field.required",
        new Object[] { "value for 1st placeholder", "value for 2nd placeholder" });
```